# Host an existing ASP.NET Website and Sql Server database (with huge size) on to Azure platform

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

We have a developed ASP.NET website that is running on our local server. The application size is 90GB (containing pictures that update daily from an external source) and Database size is 300GB. Now our client wants to move this entire stuff on to Windows Azure Platform. Since there is a storage limitation for Database (max 150GB) on Azure, how we host this much size of application and database on to Azure platform?

Below are the software requirements we are using

- Windows Server 2012 Standard
- .Net framework 4.0
- SQL Server 2012 Standard
- IIS 8.0

Thanks in advance,
Kiran

Answer (score 0):

The 150GB storage limitation you mentioned is specific to Azure SQL Database service (SQL-as-a-Service), where each database instance may be up to 150GB. This is a multi-tenant service, where you don't have any server to manage; you simply request databases, and you may create logical servers in any data center (with many databases per logical server). To go beyond 150GB, you'd need to do some type of partitioning across your SQL Database databases (maybe by customer?) or remove large objects (such as graphics images) from SQL and store them in blob storage (more on that in a moment).

**[EDIT]** With SQL Database Premium, you'll be able to go up to 500GB per database, along with geo-replication, self-service restore, and higher uptime SLA (this was all announced at //build/ 2014). More details are [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2014/04/04/sql-database-updates-coming-soon-to-the-premium-preview.aspx).

If you want larger database volumes, you may install SQL Server in a Virtual Machine. You may then attach *durable* data disks, each disk being up to 1TB, and 2 disks per core (so a maximum of 16 1TB disks). You can choose to stripe them, build data volumes, etc. That's all up to you.

If you're storing your images in SQL right now, you can consider moving those to blob storage and just storing URLs in the SQL database. This would reduce your SQL footprint. Azure storage lets you go up to 200TB per account, and you can have multiple storage accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL DB Premium should meet your requirements, the link in the previous reply is outdated, here is the current link: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741336.aspx